# How to avoid type conversion errors when retrieving cell values?

Tags: vb.net, excel

I use Vb.net 2013 excel. I need to get `.range("An")` value from a workbook cell.

How can I avoid type conversion errors when retrieving cell values without knowing the data type in advance?

How can I determine the data type decimal, integer, date, string, etc. before I get the cell value?

Using `.Cell(1,1).Text` does not give me the value I need.

I have seen some discussion from vba6 users that solve this problem with Variant Type, but this is not supported by vb.net.

I just need individual cell, so `Sheet.Arrays` may not be the answer.

Any suggestions appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When data comes in any shape and form, you need check its type and see if it can be converted to desired type. I assume you're using `Excel.Interop`. Declare your value as `Object` and test it and then try to convert it

For example

```
' Get single cell value
Dim val as Object = DirectCast(range.Cells[row, col], Excel.Range).Value2
' Test for datatypes
If TypeOf val Is Integer Then
    Dim i As Integer = CInt(val)
Else If TypeOf val Is Double Then
    ....
    ....
    ' check all datatypes here
End If
```

If you trying to convert, without checking the type, you can definitely run into conversion exceptions, and if you try to go via string as follows

```
' Get string    
 Dim val as String = DirecCast(range.Cells[row, col], Excel.Range).Value2.ToString()
 Dim i as Integer
 Dim done as Boolean
 If Not done AndAlso Integer.TryParse(val, i) Then
     ' Do something with "i"
     done = true
 End if
 ' check for other types in similar fashion but order so that types with decimals come after integers
```

In this case you may run into conditions that one type is taken for another.

Comment: Thanks T.S. I will try this approach and will post results because I have spent many hours searching for an answers.